# Rewriting SQL to ActiveRecord

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord, rails-activerecord

I am trying to rewrite this old Rails 2 stuff such that it will work with Rails 3.2.1:

**Rails 2.2.2 query to rewrite**

```
 B2bPrivilege.find_by_sql("SELECT b2b_privileges.*, vendors.name AS vendor_name FROM b2b_privileges LEFT JOIN vendors ON vendors.id = b2b_privileges.vendor_id WHERE b2b_user_id = ?", current_user_id)
```

This is what I came up with and it creates the same SQL as seen in the Rails 2.2.2 example above but it doesn't bring in the vendors.name column into the stored result and I don't know why. The generated SQL when ran in the database console, does work so the issue is definitely related to Rails.

```
    B2bPrivilege.select("b2b_privileges.*, vendors.name AS vendor_name").joins('LEFT JOIN  vendors ON vendors.id = b2b_privileges.vendor_id').where('b2b_user_id' => current_user_id)
```

**Debug info from .inspect**

```
  B2bPrivilege Load (1.4ms)  SELECT b2b_privileges.*, vendors.name AS vendor_name FROM "b2b_privileges" LEFT JOIN vendors ON vendors.id = b2b_privileges.vendor_id WHERE "b2b_privileges"."b2b_user_id" = 398
[ 
    #<B2bPrivilege id: 1363, b2b_user_id: 398, vendor_id: 53, can_setup_instant_electronic_delivery: true, can_setup_purchase_orders: true, can_setup_advance_ship_notification: true, can_setup_xml_pushes: true>, 
    #<B2bPrivilege id: 1923, b2b_user_id: 398, vendor_id: 103, can_setup_instant_electronic_delivery: false, can_setup_purchase_orders: false, can_setup_advance_ship_notification: true, can_setup_xml_pushes: true>
]
```

Answer (score 1):

It turns out the joined content is there it just doesn't output to console, just the primary relation does. If you are viewing the output in your console window I think that the console output only reflects/inspects the root level object that is returned.

This was a gotcha for me when I was debugging my queries that use joins

Answer (score 0):

Do

```
B2bPrivilege.joins('LEFT JOIN  vendors ON vendors.id = b2b_privileges.vendor_id').
  where(:b2bprivileges => {'b2b_user_id' => current_user_id} ).
  select("b2b_privileges.*, vendors.name AS 'vendor_name'").first.vendor_name
```

Comment: Thanks. I tried your variation and it returns the same results - Still missing the column from the joined table

Comment: Sorry, I missed the quotes.

Comment: I tested it with and without quotes and it works fine.  Show the tables structure.

Comment: Thanks again. Looks like you are using associations in your example - (:b2bprivileges) My models don't use associations. It turns out the joined content is there it just doesn't report to console, just the primary relation does. If you are viewing the output in your console window I think that the console output only reflects/inspects the root level object that is returned.